# View is not being updated. ComboBox does not represent the actual value

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, combobox

There are many related questions on the net, addressing the apparently same issue; however, none of the answers was helpful to me.

The basic scenario in short:
I have a dialog containing a ComboBox and a Reset-Button. The ComboBox has a Binding to the ViewModel. When the button is clicked, I'd like to update the item in the ComboBox. This does not work.

```
<ComboBox x:Name="EditorFonts" SelectedValue="{Binding FontValue, Mode=TwoWay}" />
```

The obvious answer or counter-question is: do I used OnNotifyPropertyChanged? Well, yes, basically I do, the following method is being called...

```
private void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
{
  var handler = PropertyChanged;
  if (handler != null)
  {
    handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
  }
}
```

However, PropertyChanged is NULL; thus, the if-block is not raised and nothing happens.

I also found on the net that there might be a problem with SelectedValue, and I should try using SelectedItem instead. This doesn't help either.

And even if I update the ComboBox value directly (and do not use Source-to-Target-Binding), the view isn't updated.

At this point I need to add some further details about the implementation that I, unfortunately, cannot provide as code. For one it's way to complex and for another I do not all code parts. Here's a brief explanation:

The dialog box itself is provided by another team. They own the Reset-Button. And they provide an interface. When implementing this interface and using MEF Exports, my subpage will be shown in the dialog and I get notified when the Reset-Button is clicked. This all is implemented in another assembly and I do not know a lot about their implementation.
So, when I get the notification about the Reset-Button, I try to refresh the value as described above. As this didn't work, I put an own Reset-Button (let's call it Reset2) next to my ComboBox. When Reset2 is triggered, I raise the very same code and now the ComboBox is being updated. Also, the PropertyChanged is **not** NULL.

My conclusion is, that the implementation of my DataBinding cannot be wrong. Actually, when closing the dialog and opening it again (after using Reset1), the ComboBox represents the correct value.
Furthermore, it doesn't matter to which property I bind.

I tried any of the following mechanisms to refresh the ComboBox but to no success.

```
BindingExpression be = Value.GetBindingExpression(ComboBox.SelectedValueProperty);
be.UpdateTarget();

EditorFonts.Dispatcher.Invoke(emptyDelegate, DispatcherPriority.Render);

EditorFonts.InvalidateVisual();
EditorFonts.InvalidateProperty(ComboBox.SelectedValueProperty);
EditorFonts.InvalidateMeasure();
EditorFonts.InvalidateArrange();
EditorFonts.UpdateLayout();
```

I'm pretty sure that once I found out why the PropertyChanged value is NULL, the ComboBox will be updated properly. However, I've got absolutely no idea how to fix this issue.

So, does anyone have any guesses on what's might be going wrong? What else I can look for, as the trivial issues regarding DataBinding (like not calling OnPropertyChanged) are not the cause.

---

I tried a dirty "hack" which is whenever Reset1 is clicked, I raise an event on Reset2.Clicked:

```
Reset2.RaiseEvent(new RoutedEventArgs(Button.ClickEvent));
```

Then PropertyChanged does indeed not equal NULL, but–funny enough–the ComboBox is still not updated.
I don't not for what purpose I tried that, but I was sure that it would succeed, so I'm more confused now about why the ComboBox refuses to show what I'd like to see.

Comment: Didi you make a call to OnPropertyChanged("SelectedValue"); in your Selected Value property ??

Comment: @Alvaro Well, first I just changed the dummy name as this wasn't very representative (having the same name as the Property I'm binding to); however, yes, I do that. If I wouldn't do so, the Reset2 wouldn't work either, because–as said–I'm using the very same code (just the way how to get there is different).

Answer (score 0):

When using the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface, it is customary to see code like this:

```
var handler = PropertyChanged;
if (handler != null)
{
    handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
}
```

What this means in plain English is this:

> If there are any event handlers attached to the `PropertyChanged` event, then call them with this `PropertyChangedEventArgs` object

Therefore, if `handler` is `null`, then no handlers have been attached to that event.

Comment: Well, and what could the reason be, that a handler disappears in certain cases(what happens when using Reset1), while in other the handler still exists(what is true when using Reset2). Imho, a handler is either attached or not attached, but not first one thing, then another.

Comment: That is what debugging is for.

Comment: It really shouldn't be too hard to track down... there shouldn't be too many places in your code with `"PropertyChanged += "`... just search for that.